# Circuits problem

Tags: dc, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhAjBz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My question is what's the voltage between C and D?

R7=1kΩ

Vc-Vd = (Vc-Vb)/1000 + (Vb-Va)/1000 + (Va-Vd)/1000 = ¿Vc-Vd/1000? I'm in a loop.

So Vba = Vb-Va/1000 because its a open circuit, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 3001V.

Here is my method and calculations. I started by removing the A and B connections because they don't serve any purpose in solving for Vcd.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdHQUa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From here, we know that the current in the loop is 1A because of the current source and kirchoffs current law. Now, we find the voltage drop across the resistors. For each resistor it is:

```
V = (1A)(1000ohm) = 1000V
```

Now I just summed the voltages in the loop to be zero and calculated the voltage across the current source, which will be Vcd.

```
Vcd - 1000 - 1000 - 1 - 1000 = 0
Vcd = 3001V
```

The voltage between A and B is 1001V by the way.

Comment: one mistake from me, it's 1mA not 1A. So Vcd = 4.

Comment: @FranNavarro Haha, yes, that makes much more sense.

Comment: Think in that: change R3 and current source by R3 in parallel with a voltage source. Vcd it's the voltage source and using V=IxR, Why is not the same result?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Do you mind drawing it up on circuit lab and sending a link to me?

Comment: Equivalent sources theorem.

Comment: http://s27.postimg.org/mmwg3jl0z/Screenshot_from_2015_02_16_02_48_56.png

Comment: You are doing the source transformation backwards. You transform a voltage source in series with a resistor to a current source parallel with a resistor. It does give you the same results, here's an example. https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/evp27d/screenshot/1024x768/

Comment: that's all. Thank you for your time. I cleared concepts